# Filter dataframe for values that are below or exceed min/max value that is specified in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe of values and I want to filter and transpose the dataframe if the quarterly value is under the MinRange or over the MaxRange. Values are ignored if it is inbetween the min/maxrange.

```
Name  MinRange MaxRange 2020Q1 2020Q2 2020Q3 2020Q4
Test1 15       20       13     16     24     17
Test2 18       25       14     15     23     19
Test3 30       39       31     29     24     37
```

Desired Result:

```
Quarter Name  MinRange MaxRange Value
2020Q1  Test1 15       20       13
2020Q3  Test1 15       20       24
2020Q1  Test2 18       25       14
2020Q2  Test2 18       25       15
2020Q2  Test3 30       39       29
2020Q3  Test3 30       39       24
```

Does any ideas on how I could tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are most likely more efficient ways to tackle this, but below is a simplistic brute force method. Note that I stored the original values to the df org_df

```
test_values = org_df["Name"]
quarter_values = org_df.columns.drop(["Name", "MinRange", "MaxRange"])
new_data = []
for test in test_values:
    min_value = org_df.loc[org_df["Name"]==test]["MinRange"].item()
    max_value = org_df.loc[org_df["Name"]==test]["MaxRange"].item()
    for quarter in quarter_values:
        if (org_df.loc[org_df["Name"]==test][quarter].item() < min_value) or (org_df.loc[org_df["Name"]==test][quarter].item() > max_value):
            new_data.append([
                quarter, 
                test, 
                min_value, 
                max_value, 
                org_df.loc[org_df["Name"]==test][quarter].item()
            ])
        
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=["Quarter", "Name", "MinRange", "MaxRange", "Value"])
```